# R - riverplot formatting nodes

Tags: r, sankey-diagram, riverplot

I have been fiddling around with the riverplot package and have produced some very attractive and illustrative results. I am now trying to produce a somewhat more complicated plot and some of the results that I am getting are a little unexpected. I have a minimal example which illustrates the problem. Here is the plot:

[image: riverplot example with anomalous node widths]

My problem lies with the widths of nodes B, C and E. The idea with these plots (as I understand it) is that the width of the node is determined by the total width of the rivers flowing into/out of the nodes. Now for nodes A, D and F this is certainly the case. But the other three nodes are either wider/narrower than their attached rivers. It's not a big deal, but it does detract from the impact of the plot.

Either I have made a mistake in constructing my data or I am misunderstanding the way that the package works internally. In either case, I would really appreciate any feedback!

Best regards,
Andrew.

Here is the code. The data structure was dumped with dput().

```
library(riverplot)

RP <- structure(list(
  nodes = structure(
    list(
      ID = structure(c(1L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 6L), .Label = c("A", "D", "B", "E", "C", "F"), class = "factor"),
      x = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L)
    ), .Names = c("ID", "x"), row.names = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), class = "data.frame"), 
  edges = structure(
    list(
      N1 = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"),
      N2 = c("D", "E", "F", "D", "E", "F", "D", "E", "F"),
      Value = c(0.265, 0.372, 0.572, 0.908, 0.201, 0.898, 0.944, 0.660, 0.629)
    ), .Names = c("N1", "N2", "Value"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")),
  .Names = c("nodes", "edges"), class = c("list", "riverplot"))

plot(RP, plot_area = 0.85)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, there was a minor bug in the riverplot package. The package author has fixed it and the new version (v0.3) will work fine for this case.